# Lists unintentionally change simultaneously

Tags: python, json, list, function, oop

The [function](https://pastebin.com/h3wfLkBy) of my Python library takes a predefined list of dictionaries from `file_contents` (`file_contents` is from a *.json file, the path to this file is specified in `self.full_path`) and changes these dictionaries.

The thing is it:

1. Takes `changed_list_dictionaries` as a copy of `start_list_dictionaries`.
2. Then changes the `changed_list_dictionaries` to the needed values.
3. Deletes all the dictionaries from `file_contents` which are in `start_list_dictionaries`.
4. Extends `file_contents` with the dictionaries in `changed_list_dictionaries`.

I have encountered the problem: lists `start_list_dictionaries` and `changed_list_dictionaries` change simultaneously, though should not. How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

```py
def change_several_books(self, start_list_dictionaries):
        changed_list_dictionaries = start_list_dictionaries.copy()
        shortest_dict = min(changed_list_dictionaries, key=len)
        dict_for_change = shortest_dict.copy()
        for key, value in dict_for_change.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for desc, type_value in value.items():
                    new_value = input(f"--------<{desc}>: ")
                    if new_value in ["del", "<del>"]:
                        dict_for_change[key] = "<del>"
                    elif new_value == "":
                        dict_for_change[key] = "<continue>"
                    else:
                        if isinstance(type_value, (str, int, dict)):
                            changed_dictionary[key_in_initial_dict] = {desc: new_value}
                        elif isinstance(type_value, list):
                            try:
                                changed_dictionary[key_in_initial_dict] =\
                                    {desc: json.loads(new_value)}
                            except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                                changed_dictionary[key_in_initial_dict] =\
                                    {desc: [new_value]}
           
 
        for dictionary in changed_list_dictionaries:
            for initial_key in dictionary.copy().keys():
                for key_for_change, value_for_change in dict_for_change.items():
                    if initial_key == key_for_change:
                        if value_for_change == "<continue>":
                            pass
                        elif value_for_change == "<del>":
                            del dictionary[initial_key]
                        elif isinstance(value_for_change, dict):
                            dictionary[initial_key] = value_for_change
 
        with open(self.full_path, 'r') as file:
            file_contents = json.load(file)
 
        file_contents = [
            element
            for element in file_contents
            if element not in start_list_dictionaries
        ]
        file_contents.extend(changed_list_dictionaries)
 
        with open(self.full_path, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(file_contents, file)
 
        print("\nSuccess!")
```

Comment: Show the code in the question. You are almost certainly *not* making a copy of the list as you are claiming in point 1.

Comment: Hmm, my first suggestion wasn't correct. The issue is that you're making _shallow_ copies and not _deepcopies_

Comment: I am so grateful for the deepcopy remark! It works as I want after importing the "copy" library and using the deepcopy. Thanks! Please, write it as an answer, I'll upvote and mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `start_list_dictionaries.copy()` returns a shallow copy of your list ([documentation on data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)), but you want a *deep* copy. The difference in a shallow and deep copy is important when the object you're copying is a collection of collections. ([Docs for shallow and deep copying](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)) In your case you have a `list` of `dict` objs. A shallow copy of `start_list_dictionaries` will make a new list of new *references* to the *same old dicts*. But what you want is a *new* list of *new copies* of these dicts. That is the basic difference in shallow copying and deep copying.

In many cases using built-in types (like `list` and `dict`), a deep copy can be obtained like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy

obj_dc = deepcopy(obj)
```